# How registrate two class with circular references in DWScript?

Tags: dwscript

I need to register TCollection and TCollectionItem classes, but because of the properties of

```
{TCollection}
property Items [Index: Integer]: TCollectionItem
{TCollectionItem}
property Collection: TCollection
```

сonstantly raises the exception of the impossibility to find TCollectionItem/TCollectionItem type.

Comment: Do you use the auto RTTI register class or do you register the class on you own?

Answer (score 0):

If you register the class on you own within code, you could first register the `TCollectionItem` without the `property Collection: TCollection`, then register `TCollection` with `property Items [Index: Integer]: TCollectionItem` and afterwards adding the `property Collection: TCollection` to your `TCollectionItem`.

Comment: But exception is raised in DoGenerate procedure when code compiling. How I can register property Collection: TCollection before TCollection class registration???

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
type
  TCollection = class;

  TCollectionItem = class
  published
    property Items: TCollection;
  end;

  TCollection = class
  published
    property Items [Index: Integer]: TCollectionItem;
  end;
```